# How to check that they belong to the same class in c++ test Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to check if the constructor is initialized correctly, but I don't know which assert method to use

```
TEST_METHOD(testInitNavigator)
        {
            Room room;
            INavigator navigator(room);
            Assert::AreSame(room, navigator.getLocalRoom());
        }
```

Comment: What is your definition of "same"? That there's only one object and both variables *references* that single object? Or that two object are equal when compared with `==`? Something else? You need to make this clear for yourself first, before you can test for them to be the "same".

Comment: sorry the translator translated incorrectly. I meant that they belong to the same type

Comment: Then I'm not really sure I understand the test. What does `navigator.getLocalRoom()` return? Does it return a `Room` object? Then of course `room` and `navigator.getLocalRoom()` would have the "same" type.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to add more details so others can understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is correct so

```
        TEST_METHOD(testInitNavigator)
        {
            Room room;
            INavigator navigator(room);
            Assert::IsTrue(typeid(room).name() == typeid(navigator.getLocalRoom()).name());
        }
```

Comment: Note that [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) (which is the type of the object returned by `typeid`) already have a direct [equality operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp).

Comment: And *also* note that [type_info::name()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is not strictly required to return a unique name.